# Batch Command to search multiple files for a particular key word/number?

Tags: batch-file, menu, full-text-search

I am in the process of creating a batch menu for each application that a call traverses through in our Telephony platform.

When I select each application I want to create another menu item that then takes you to an option to search for a phone number in a particular directory that holds multiple files?

I have only started to learn batch but this is what I have so far:

```
@ECHO off
TITLE False Positive Search
:menu
echo ..........................................
echo . Press 1,2,3,4,5 or 6 to select your MCP.
echo ..........................................
echo
echo enter 1) MCP_1_P_DC1
echo enter 2) MCP_2_P_DC1
echo enter 3) MCP_3_P_DC1
echo enter 4) MCP_4_P_DC1
echo enter 5) MCP_5_P_DC1
echo enter 6) MCP_6_P_DC1
set /p ans="Enter Number: "

if %ans%==1 (
goto a
)
if %ans%==2 (
goto b
)
if %ans%==3 (
goto c
)
if %ans%==4 (
goto d
)
if %ans%==5 (
goto e
)
if %ans%==6 (
goto f
)

:a
echo MCP_1_P_DC1 Menu
pause
goto menu

:b
echo MCP_2_P_DC1 Menu
pause
goto menu

:c
echo MCP_2_P_DC1 Menu
pause
goto menu

:d
echo MCP_2_P_DC1 Menu
pause
goto menu

:e
echo MCP_2_P_DC1 Menu
pause
goto menu

:f
echo MCP_2_P_DC1 Menu
pause
goto menu
```

Comment: Take a look to `find /?` and `findstr /?`

Comment: the other thing is my string will be different every time I search.  I am search for the word "great" all the time.  I will be searching for a new phone number in each search.

Comment: take a look to `set /?` and parameters (described in `call /?`)